# zookeeper server shutdown after some time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

we have HDP cluster version 2.6.4 with 3 zookeeper server version 3.4.x

the first zookeeper server not working as should be and stooped after some time

from ambari GUI we can see that zoo disconnected

from the zookeeper log we can see the following:

```
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1082)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
2018-06-12 18:35:01,856 - ERROR [CommitProcessor:1:NIOServerCnxn@178] - Unexpected Exception:
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1082)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
2018-06-12 18:35:01,857 - ERROR [CommitProcessor:1:NIOServerCnxn@178] - Unexpected Exception:
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1082)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
2018-06-12 18:35:01,857 - ERROR [CommitProcessor:1:NIOServerCnxn@178] - Unexpected Exception:
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1082)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
2018-06-12 18:35:01,857 - ERROR [CommitProcessor:1:NIOServerCnxn@178] - Unexpected Exception:
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1082)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
2018-06-12 18:35:01,857 - ERROR [CommitProcessor:1:NIOServerCnxn@178] - Unexpected Exception:
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1082)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
2018-06-12 18:35:01,857 - ERROR [CommitProcessor:1:NIOServerCnxn@178] - Unexpected Exception:
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1082)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:391)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
```

and when we do a test for the zookeeper we got that:

```
echo stat | nc 14.42.169 2181

Latency min/avg/max: 0/10/2727
Received: 600879
Sent: 103803
Connections: 30
Outstanding: 546
Zxid: 0x3e000048c3
Mode: follower
Node count: 43296
```

- note that *send* is much less then we got from *Received!*

and we can see that many CLOSE-WAIT connections

```
#  ss -anop | grep 2181 | grep CLOSE | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | more
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
tcp CLOSE-WAIT
```

in order to try to resolve this issue we performed the following but without success

1. increase Java heap size to 8G ( only on zookeeper )
2. increase zookeeper.session.timeout.ms on kafka

but all these not help us

please advice what could be the reason for this issue ,

Comment: What is the ram provided to the cluster?

Comment: each machine have 32G , but this isnt the problem I check by free -g

Comment: @KingDavid - Is your Zookeeper running on virtual servers or physical servers? If it is virtual then, is the storage shared or direct attached storage?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a fixed bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2044

Try to update your zookeeper